# Dagster error - attempt to write a readonly database

Tags: dagster

I'm trying to set up a gRPC server for Dagster.  I have the gRPC server running in one process, runing the simple hello-dagster app, and Dagster in another.  When I go to materialize the assets, I get the following error:

```
dagster._core.errors.DagsterLaunchFailedError: Error during RPC setup for executing run: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) attempt to write a readonly database
[SQL: PRAGMA main.table_info("alembic_version")]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
```

In searching for a solution to this problem, I ran across a similar issue [here](https://github.com/dagster-io/dagster/issues/18029), but with no solution provided.  This issue made reference to permissions on the directory indicated by `DAGSTER_HOME`.  The permissions of this directory on my system (Linux) are: `drwxrwxr-x`.

Anyone have any thoughts about how to fix this error, or how to determine where the persmissions problem lies (if, indeed, that is the problem)?